# Suggest a WYSIWYG GUI creator for Perl

Tags: perl, user-interface, wysiwyg

I am looking for a WYSIWYG GUI creator. I searched on Google and I found 
[VisualCamel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/visualcamel/) but this is not for Linux.

Let me know if there are more such creators available for Linux. I find it hard to use Perl/Tk module and then code in it. I wish for a GUI builder like Visual basic.

Comment: There are creators available for Tk, Gui Bulder (formerly spectcl) which targets various Tk bindings available at http://spectcl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

[Padre Form Builder](http://blogs.perl.org/users/adam_kennedy/2011/07/padre-form-builder---a-cross-platform-gui-design-solution-for-perl.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can design the interface with [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) and load the XML interface file with [gtk2-perl](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, VisualCamel is written in perl, so it will run on linux, provided that you install perl, install Tk module (and any other prerequisites)

spectcl (or any Tcl GUI Builder) along with perl module Tkx

wxGlade along with perl module Wx

Glade along with perl module Gtk2::GladeXML